# Mono - All the doOnError handlers are getting called

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I have this Mono code:

```
return Mono.just(operation)
        .map(this::validate)
        .then(execute(operation))
        .doOnError(ValidationException.class, this::handleValidationException)
        .doOnError(Exception.class, this::handleException);
```

When the validate method throws ValidationException, both handleValidationException and handleException are called. i am expecting call only to handleValidationException.
Why is this happening ? How to prevent handleException from getting called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When the validate method throws ValidationException, both handleValidationException and handleException are called. i am expecting call only to handleValidationException. Why is this happening ?

...because `ValidationException` is also an instance of `Exception` through inheritance, and `doOnError()` won't "swallow" the exception (so it still propagates through to the next `doOnError()` call.

There's a few different ways you could handle it - my preferred way is usually to use `onErrorResume()` to swallow the exception and return an empty publisher once you've handled it:

```
//...
.then(execute(operation))
.onErrorResume(ValidationException.class, e -> {
    this.handleValidationException();
    return Mono.empty();
})
.doOnError(Exception.class, ...)
```

...this will then ensure errors can never "fall-through", if that's the behaviour you're after.

Two other approaches spring to mind as well, however, I like these far less. You could use a predicate to explicitly check if it's not a `ValidationException` in your second `doOnError()`:

```
.doOnError(e -> !(e instanceof ValidationException), ...)
```

...or you could also handle all the exceptions in one block and just check the type in there:

```
.doOnError(e -> {
    if(e instanceof ValidationException) {

    }
    else {

    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I wanted to avoid following the last approach but that seems to be the simplest. I need the exception to fall through so i have no other choice :)